# Signup by jwt in springboot webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, basic-authentication

I am a beginner on writing the webflux,but i am currectly writing a jwt authentication on springboot cloud apigateway.However, i found that i am just stuck on the signup part and reactive syntax due to the less resource on the internet.Here are my code:
signup service:

```
public Mono<String> signup(SignupDto user)  {

return IsUsernameExist(user.getUsername()).
                         doOnNext(System.out::println)
                         .flatMap(isNameExist->{
                     if(isNameExist){
                         log.error("Username have already exist");
                         return Mono.empty();
                     }
                     Mono<user_info> savedusr = respository.save(new user_info(0, user.getUsername(),
                             passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()),
                             user.getFullName(),
                             user.getEmail(),
                             user.getSkill_set(), user.getContact(), user.getCv(), user.getAddress_id()
                             , user.getAddress(), null, 3));
                     log.info("generating token");
                     //error
                     if (savedusr.equals(Mono.empty())){
                         log.info("error occur");

                         return Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("error occur"));
                     }
                     return reactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(
                             new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                     user.getUsername(),user.getPassword()
                             )
                     ).map(this::generateToken
                     )
                             ;


                 });
```

IsUsernameExist:

```
private Mono<Boolean> IsUsernameExist(String username){
        return respository.findByyUsername(username).doOnNext(res-> System.out.print(" "))
                .map(res->{
                            if (res==null){
                                return false;
                            }
                    log.error("repeated username");
                            return true;
                        }
                );
```

log:

```
2023-02-03T03:54:33.793+08:00 DEBUG 98479 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.d.r2dbc.core.NamedParameterExpander  : Expanding SQL statement [SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = :username ;] to [SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = ? ;]
```

Only this log and empty respond are shown after it test the api on postman.It seems that it is because my code in signup service isnt been run(the log not appear) and i am just wondering why.Here are the reference code.I know there should many mistakes on my code,but please give my some advice.Any pointers for me is fine

generatetoken:

```
 public String generateToken(Authentication user){
        log.info("generate token");

        Instant now=Instant.now();
        String scope=user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        String secret="AMDM:LM:LSMLdfsf";

         Mono<Integer> MonoId =respository.findByyUsername(user.getName())
                 .map(user_info::getId);


        JwtClaimsSet claims=JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:8080")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(user.getName())

                .claim("scope",scope)
                .claim("secret",secret)
                
                .build();
        return this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();

    }
```

Securityfilterchain:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                /*.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/Job/getRegionjobs/**",
                        "/Job/getalljobs","/login/oauth2/code/google"))*/
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())

                .authorizeExchange(auth->
                        auth.pathMatchers("/signup","/signin").permitAll()

                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                       )

             
                .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
                
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                
                .build();
```

ReactiveAuthManger :

```
 @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws TypeMismatchException {
        log.info("Received authentication request");

        Mono<String> password=securityUserService.findByUsername(authentication.getName())
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .map(UserDetails::getPassword);

        return Mono.just(authentication)
                .doOnNext(authentication1 -> System.out.println("start"))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                    .map(auth->{
                        System.out.println(passwordEncoder.encode(auth.getCredentials().toString()));
                        //if(Mono.just(passwordEncoder.matches(auth.getCredentials().toString(),password.doOnNext(System.out::println).subscribe()))){

                                password.map(
                                res -> {
                            log.info("STart match");
                            if(passwordEncoder.matches(auth.getCredentials().toString(), res)){
                        log.info("password match");
                         return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                 auth.getName(),null,auth.getAuthorities()
                         );

                    }else {
                            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credients");

                        }

                    });
                        return auth;
                    });
}}
```

SecurityUserService:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class SecurityUserService implements ReactiveUserDetailsService {


    private final UserRespository userRespository;

    public SecurityUserService(UserRespository userRespository) {
        this.userRespository = userRespository;
    }


    @Override
    public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {

            log.info("get user");

        return userRespository.findByyUsername(username)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                .map(
                      SecurityUser::new
              );
```

Comment: You are breaking the chain `savedusr` you need to use this variable. But instead you ignore it and return a `reactiveAuthenticationManager`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the finding existing user function logic is wrong after i observe the debug log.
Here is my final version and it finally works:

```
private Mono<Boolean> IsUsernameExist(String username){
        return respository.findByyUsername(username)
                .doOnNext(res-> System.out.print(" afdasd"))
                .doOnError(res->{log.info("good");
                    Mono.just(false);
                })
                .map(res->true
                );


 public Mono<String> signup(user_info user)  {

          log.info("signup start");
        return Mono.just(user).doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                     .flatMap(Monouser->{
                 Mono<Boolean> isuserexist=IsUsernameExist(Monouser.getUsername())
                         .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                         .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(false))  //no user found => can register
                         .mapNotNull(res-> res
                         );
                 Monouser.setPassword(  //encode the password
                                 passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                 Mono<user_info> savedusr = respository.save(
                 Monouser).log();

                        return isuserexist.doOnNext(System.out::println) //check the username exist in my db
                                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                                .flatMap(
                                res->{
                                    log.info("start the map");
                                    if(res){
                                    log.info("error");
                                    return null;
                                }
                                else {
                                    savedusr.subscribe();  //execute the saving user
                                    log.info("check");
                                    return reactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(
                                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                                    user.getUsername(),user.getPassword()
                                            )
                                    ).map(this::generateToken)
                                           

                                            ;
                                }
   });}
```

It seems  that there are still have many flaws in my code.Any advice are welcome for me thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).